# VB - Concatenation of two String-variables fails

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, visual-studio, concatenation

I try to concatenate two variables of type string, and my result is only the first variable:

```
Function newXlsx(ByVal sFilepath As String) As Boolean
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim sTest As String

    sTest = sFilepath.Trim()
    sFileName = Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd") & ".xls*"
    MsgBox(sTest & "\" & sFileName)

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(sFilepath & "\" & sFileName) Then
        MsgBox("File found.")
    Else
        MsgBox("File not found.")
    End If
End Function
```

Note: `sFilepath` given to the function is "H:\A74" with multiple spaces after the "4", thats why I `Trim()` the string. So `sTest` is "H:\A74" and `sFileName` is "2016-06-22.xls*" but the result is not "H:\A74\2016-06-22.xls*" how I would expect it, instead it is just "H:\A74".

Comment: You should learn how to use break point and step through your code, this would help you a lot into finding these problems.

Comment: i described the problem as precise as I could. I used bp's to find the problem, its the concatenation.

Comment: The asterisk at the end of the extension will be a problem.

Comment: How has `sFilePath` ended up with unwanted characters?

Comment: If you run the code in your question, you should find that the `MsgBox` shows the correct path. However, that is not the path you are using in in the `FileExists` method. I think you meant to use `sTest` instead of `sFilePath` in the `FileExists` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `System.IO.Path.Combine` to prevent such issues:

```
Function newXlsx(ByVal sFilepath As String) As Boolean   
    Dim sFileName = Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & ".xls"
    Dim path = System.IO.Path.Combine(sFilepath.Trim(), sFileName)    
    Dim exists = System.IO.File.Exists(path)
    If exists Then
        MsgBox("File found.")
    Else
        MsgBox("File not found.")
    End If
    Return exists
End Function
```

Note that you are using `My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(sFilepath & "\" & sFileName)` instead of your trimmed string.

---

**Update**: Maybe your path contains invalid characters. You could use a method to remove them:

```
ReadOnly InvalidPathChars As String = New String(Path.GetInvalidPathChars())

Public Function RemoveInvalidPathChars(dirOrFileName As String) As String
    dirOrFileName = dirOrFileName.Trim()
    For Each c As Char In InvalidPathChars
        dirOrFileName = dirOrFileName.Replace(c, "")
    Next
    Return dirOrFileName
End Function
```

Then change your method accordingly to use it:

```
Function newXlsx(ByVal sFilepath As String) As Boolean
    Dim sFileName = Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & ".xls"
    Dim safePath = RemoveInvalidPathChars(sFilepath)
    Dim path = System.IO.Path.Combine(safePath, sFileName)
    Dim exists = System.IO.File.Exists(path)
    If exists Then
        MsgBox("File found.")
    Else
        MsgBox("File not found.")
    End If
    Return exists
End Function
```

Comment: I copied your code, but I get an System.ArgumentException, it' says "illegal character"

Comment: @flohdieter: where do you get this exception?

Comment: In the `Dim path = System.IO.Path.Combine(sFilepath.Trim(), sFileName)` Line

Comment: @flohdieter: What is `sFilepath` in your case? I've tried with `"H:\A74  "` and it worked without a problem.

Comment: I tried it with "H:\A74" too and it works perfectly, but the real string my program give to this function is "H:\A74_Handscan_Data" with a lot of spaces at the end. The problem seems to be at the string but i can't image what it is.

Comment: @flohdieter: then modify the `Invalid` so that it only uses `GetInvalidPathChars` and not `GetInvalidFileNameChars`, so `New String(Path.GetInvalidPathChars())`

Comment: that works,Thank you. What does the `invalid` line do?

Comment: @flohdieter: it contains all invalid path-characters. Look. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars(v=vs.110).aspx The question is why your input string contains these characters at all.

Comment: because the characters ":\" are a part of the path, where the files I want to edit are stored.

Comment: @flohdieter: yes, but that was not the problem. It wold have been worked without my `RemoveInvalidPathChars`-method if the only problem was the \ because `IO.Path.Combine` accepts this character. There was another one that caused this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IO.Path methods

```
Function newXlsx(ByVal sFilepath As String) As Boolean
    Dim spath As String
    spath = IO.Path.Combine(sFilepath.Trim, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
    spath = IO.Path.ChangeExtension(spath, "xls")

    MsgBox(spath)

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(spath) Then
        MsgBox("File found.")
    Else
        MsgBox("File not found.")
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: The `spath = IO.Path.Combine(sFilepath.Trim, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))` Line throws an  System.ArgumentException, it' says "illegal character"

Comment: It means that there is an illegal character in sFilepath, another benefit of IO.Path.  IO.Path has other methods that might be of interest https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I tried it using this         newXlsx("H:\A74_Handscan_Data                                                                        ")
 and it worked.  There are a lot of spaces after _Data though you can't see them.